# How to get the width/height of jpeg file without using library?

Tags: c, jpeg, binaryfiles

Firstly I want to say I tried many times to find the answer by using google search, and I found many results but I did not understand, because I don't know the idea of reading a binary file, and convert the value that Obtained to readable value.

**What I tried doing it.**

```
unsigned char fbuff[16];
FILE *file;
file = fopen("C:\\loser.jpg", "rb");
if(file != NULL){
   fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
   fread(fbuff, 1, 16, file);
   printf("%d\n", fbuff[1]);
   fclose(file);
}else{
   printf("File does not exists.");
}
```

**I want a simple explanation with example shows, how to get width/height of jpeg file from its header, and then convert that value to readable value.**

Comment: Do you have the details of what is contained in the jpeg files? If you have, please include it in your question. I doubt your above method will work since there is generally a header at the beginning and then the actual pixel values start. If you need only the height and width information, I believe you can get that by reading the header alone.

Comment: @mishr: I'm talking about `jpeg files` in general.

Comment: I understand that, but the question is do you know what is the format for jpeg files? Or do you want us to find it for you ?

Comment: @mishr: This is the first time to deal with binary files, like jpeg, and I don't understand anything about that.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html. It says that the header contains the width and height information at offsets 2 and 4 respectively. All you need to do is that point the `fread` to these offsets using `fseek` and read 2 bytes from each location. Then you need to convert these bytes to integers. Give it a try.

Comment: @mishr: I have done it before, but it is gives me mysterious number, how to convert that number to get the real value.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35554/discussion-between-mishr-and-lion-king)

Comment: @shm, the link you gave (http://www.fastgraph.com/help/jpeg_header_format.html) contains totally wrong information about JPEG header. Even the stamp is wrong. Then width and height at offset  2 and 4 resp/ly?  These people must be crazy.

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be simple for JPEG. You should look at the source to the [`jhead`](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/) command line tool. It provides this information. When going through the source, you will see the function `ReadJpegSections`. This function scans through all the segments contained within the JPEG file to extract the desired information. The image width and height is obtained when processing the frames that have an `SOFn` marker.

I see the source is in the public domain, so I'll show the snippet that gets the image info:

```
static int Get16m(const void * Short)
{
    return (((uchar *)Short)[0] << 8) | ((uchar *)Short)[1];
}

static void process_SOFn (const uchar * Data, int marker)
{
    int data_precision, num_components;

    data_precision = Data[2];
    ImageInfo.Height = Get16m(Data+3);
    ImageInfo.Width = Get16m(Data+5);
```

From the source code, it is clear to me there is no single "header" with this information. You have to scan through the JPEG file, parsing each segment, until you find the segment with the information in it that you want. This is described in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure):

> A JPEG image consists of a sequence of segments, each beginning with a marker, each of which begins with a 0xFF byte followed by a byte indicating what kind of marker it is. Some markers consist of just those two bytes; others are followed by two bytes indicating the length of marker-specific payload data that follows.

---

A JPEG file consists of a sequence of segments:

```
SEGMENT_0
SEGMENT_1
SEGMENT_2
...
```

Each segment begins with a 2-byte marker. The first byte is `0xFF`, the second byte determines the type of the segment. This is followed by an encoding of the length of the segment. Within the segment is data specific to that segment type.

The image width and height is found in a segment of type `SOFn`, or "Start of frame [n]", where "n" is some number that means something special to a JPEG decoder. It should be good enough to look only for a `SOF0`, and its byte designation is `0xC0`. Once you find this frame, you can decode it to find the image height and width.

So the structure of a program to do what you want would look like:

```
file_data = the data in the file
data = &file_data[0]
while (data not at end of file_data)
    segment_type = decoded JPEG segment type at data
    if (type != SOF0)
        data += byte length for segment_type
        continue
    else
        get image height and width from segment
        return
```

This is essentially the structure found in [Michael Petrov's `get_jpeg_size()` implementation](https://web.archive.org/web/20131016210645/http://www.64lines.com/jpeg-width-height).

Comment: @LionKing, let me know if the explanation is not clear, or if you need additional help.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand it, I want a very simple way and example in order to understand it.

Comment: I would very much appreciate a reason for the down vote. Thanks!

Comment: I'm so sorry but this is occurred unintentionally(incorrectly), forgive me.

Comment: @LionKing: There is really no problem. Just FYI, down votes are totally anonymous, so there is no way for me to know who down voted me. I just wanted a reason so I could improve the answer.

Answer (score 14):

then you have to find hight and width marker of jpeg that is [ffc0].

after finding ffc0 in binary formate, the the four,five bytes are hight and six and seven bytes are width.

```
eg: [ff c0] d8 c3 c2 [ff da] [00 ff]
                      |         |
                      |         |
                      ->height  ->width

int position;
unsigned char len_con[2];
/*Extract start of frame marker(FFC0) of width and hight and get the position*/
for(i=0;i<FILE_SIZE;i++)
{
    if((image_buffer[i]==FF) && (image_buffer[i+1]==c0) )
    {
        position=i;
    }
}
/*Moving to the particular byte position and assign byte value to pointer variable*/
position=position+5;
*height=buffer_src[position]<<8|buffer_src[position+1];
*width=buffer_src[position+2]<<8|buffer_src[position+3];

printf("height %d",*height);
printf("width %d",*width);
```

Answer (score 6):

the question is old and the other answers are correct but their format is not the easiest one. I just use `getc` to quickly get the dimensions, while skipping irrelevant markers (it also supports **Progressive JPEGs**):

```
  int height, width;
  // start of image (SOI)
  getc(f);   // oxff
  getc(f);   // oxd8
  // Scan miscellaneous markers until we reach SOF0 marker (0xC0)
  for(;;) {
     // next marker
     int marker;
     while((marker = getc(f)) != 0xFF);
     while((marker = getc(f)) == 0xFF);
     // SOF
     if (marker == 0xC0 || marker == 0xC2) {
        getc(f);   // length (2 bytes)
        getc(f);   // #
        getc(f);   // bpp, usually 8
        height = (getc(f) << 8) + getc(f);   // height
        width = (getc(f) << 8) + getc(f);   // width
        break;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this and all of the other answers that read all bytes will fail if the ff c0 or ff c2 segment comes after some other segment where the  payload happens to contain ff c0 / ff c2.

Comment: @Dave S never heard about byte stuffing?

Comment: @Luca When I skimmed wiki entry on the spec I read it as saying segments only did byte stuffing for entropy-coded data, so ff co / ff c2 could occur in other payloads.

Comment: @DaveS Do you know some other more reliable way to figure out this information?

Comment: @HRK44 just to do some minimal parsing, reading the record sizes and jumping past them until you see the ff c0 record.

Comment: This quickly shows the correct structure; but there could be a more robust way to walk the markers. Upvoted anyway because of the correct structure.

Answer (score 2):

Image dimensions in JPEG files can be found as follows:

1) Look for **FF C0**

2) At offsets +4 and +6 after this location are height and width (words), resp/ly.

In most cases, the absolute offsets of height and width are A3 and A5, resp/ly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some simple code I wrote which seems to work reliably.

```
#define MOTOSHORT(p) ((*(p))<<8) + *(p+1)
unsigned char cBuf[32];
int iBytes, i, j, iMarker, iFilesize;
unsigned char ucSubSample;
int iBpp, iHeight, iWidth;

         Seek(iHandle, 0, 0); // read the first 32 bytes
         iBytes = Read(iHandle, cBuf, 32);

         i = j = 2; /* Start at offset of first marker */
         iMarker = 0; /* Search for SOF (start of frame) marker */
         while (i < 32 && iMarker != 0xffc0 && j < iFileSize)
            {
            iMarker = MOTOSHORT(&cBuf[i]) & 0xfffc;
            if (iMarker < 0xff00) // invalid marker, could be generated by "Arles Image Web Page Creator" or Accusoft
               {
               i += 2;
               continue; // skip 2 bytes and try to resync
               }
            if (iMarker == 0xffc0) // the one we're looking for
               break;
            j += 2 + MOTOSHORT(&cBuf[i+2]); /* Skip to next marker */
            if (j < iFileSize) // need to read more
               {
               Seek(iHandle, j, 0); // read some more
               iBytes = Read(iHandle, cBuf, 32);
               i = 0;
               }
            else // error, abort
               break;
            } // while
         if (iMarker != 0xffc0)
            goto process_exit; // error - invalid file?
         else
            {
            iBpp = cBuf[i+4]; // bits per sample
            iHeight = MOTOSHORT(&cBuf[i+5]);
            iWidth = MOTOSHORT(&cBuf[i+7]);
            iBpp = iBpp * cBuf[i+9]; /* Bpp = number of components * bits per sample */
            ucSubSample = cBuf[i+11];
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, is the previous example by using `C/C++`?, what is `Seek`, `Read` functions ?, and What is the benefit of this function `MOTOSHORT` ?, also what is `iHandle` variable ?.

Comment: The seek and read functions are generic file i/o that should exist in all systems. The MOTOSHORT is a macro (see top of code) which is convenient for reading big endian shorts on any system regardless of endianess. The ihandle variable is the file handle that is assumed to be opened before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int  GetJpegDimensions(
    char            *pImage,
    size_t          nSize,
    unsigned32      *u32Width,
    unsigned32      *u32Height,
    char            *szErrMsg)
{
    int             nIndex;
    int             nStartOfFrame;
    int             nError = NO_ERROR;
    bool            markerFound = false;
    unsigned char   ucWord0;
    unsigned char   ucWord1;

    // verify START OF IMAGE marker = FF D8
    nIndex = 0;
    ucWord0 = pImage[nIndex];
    ucWord1 = pImage[nIndex+1];

    // marker FF D8  starts a valid JPEG
    if ((ucWord0 == 0xFF)  && (ucWord1 == 0xD8))
    {
        // search for START OF FRAME 0  marker  FF C0
        for (nIndex = 2;
            (nIndex < nSize-2) && (markerFound == false);
             nIndex += 2)
        {
            ucWord0 = pImage[nIndex];
            ucWord1 = pImage[nIndex+1];
            if (ucWord0 == 0xFF)
            {
                if (ucWord1 == 0xC0)
                {
                    markerFound = true;
                    nStartOfFrame = nIndex;
                }
            }
            if (ucWord1 == 0xFF)
            {
                ucWord0 = pImage[nIndex+2];
                if (ucWord0 == 0xC0)
                {
                    markerFound = true;
                    nStartOfFrame = nIndex+1;
                }
            }
        } // while

        if (markerFound)
        {
            nError  = NO_ERROR;
            ucWord0 = pImage[nStartOfFrame+5];
            ucWord1 = pImage[nStartOfFrame+6];
            *u32Height = ucWord1 + (ucWord0 << 8);

            ucWord0 = pImage[nStartOfFrame+7];
            ucWord1 = pImage[nStartOfFrame+8];
            *u32Width =  ucWord1 + (ucWord0 << 8);
        }
        else
        {
            // start of frame 0 not found
            nError = -2;
            sprintf(szErrMsg,
              "Not a valid JPEG image. START OF FRAME 0 marker FFC0 not found");
        }
    }
    else   // START OF IMAGE marker not found
    {
        nError = -1;
        sprintf(szErrMsg,
          "Not a valid JPEG image. START OF IMAGE marker FFD8 not found");
    }
    return nError;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code i wrote in Java. Works fine for jpegs taken from a camera. It scans all the code to find the biggest image size. I could not improve it to skip on the lengths of each block because it doesn't work. If anyone can improve the code to do that it would be great.

```
int getShort(byte[] p, int i)
{
   int p0 = p[i] & 0xFF;
   int p1 = p[i+1] & 0xFF;
   return p1 | (p0 << 8);
}

int[]  GetJpegDimensions(byte[] b)
{
    int nIndex;
    int height=0, width=0, size=0;
    int nSize = b.length;

    // marker FF D8  starts a valid JPEG
    if (getShort(b,0) == 0xFFD8)
       for (nIndex = 2; nIndex < nSize-1; nIndex += 4)
          if (b[nIndex] == -1/*FF*/ && b[nIndex+1] == -64/*C0*/)
          {
             int w = getShort(b,nIndex+7);
             int h = getShort(b,nIndex+5);
             if (w*h > size)
             {
                size = w*h;
                width = w;
                height = h;
             }
          }
    return new int[]{width,height};
}
```