# getting the shape of an image file from python without loading the image

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

Is there an efficient way to know the size (height, weight, channels) of an image file, without actually loading it into python?

The trivial way would be:

```
img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
print img.shape
```

but that would waste the CPU (and memory) as I don't need the image itself.

Comment: In the case of JPEG it is not trivial, since the image attributes are not stored in a plain, reader-friendly format. Instead, JPEG data is stored as a concatenation of segments. I found this answer quite interesting: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18264693/2863154)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

PIL's `Image.open` doesn't load the image data until it needs to, as seen in the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open),

> This is a lazy operation; this function identifies the file, but the
>   file remains open and the actual image data is not read from the file
>   until you try to process the data (or call the load() method). See
>   new().

To check this in `ipython` I ran

```
im = Image.open(filename)
im.size
```

on a 22MB image, `ps -av` reported:

```
33714 17772  0.8 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/ipython2
34506 18220  0.8 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/ipython2
34506 18220  0.8 /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/ipython2
```

for memory usage, before `open`, before `size` and after `size`, confirming that the 22MB image hasn't been loaded into memory (`ipython` started out using `32538 17252`).
That figure then jumps up to ~57k following `im.load()`.