# fast way to read height width and file size of jpeg without decoding

Tags: swift, macos, jpeg, nsfilemanager

I have a list of jpegs that I need to check if they are under 4096px and if the file size is below 4MB. I don't need to display the image so loading the full file and decoding it is a bit overkill.

is it possible to get only height, width from metadata and file size?

on mac os with swift

Comment: See [How to get the width/height of jpeg file without using library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264357/how-to-get-the-width-height-of-jpeg-file-without-using-library)

Comment: See [How to get the file size given a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815471/how-to-get-the-file-size-given-a-path)

Comment: Really quick, really dirty and needing adapting for swift, but nonetheless... http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/45217/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size could be checked by [FileManager API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager).

Image width and height could be checked via [CGImageSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimagesource-r84) functions (ImageIO.framework) without loading the image to memory:

```
do {
    let attribute = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: filePath)

    // Filesize
    let fileSize = attribute[FileAttributeKey.size] as! Int

    // Width & Height
    let imageFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageFileUrl as CFURL, nil) {
        if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {

            let width = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
            let height = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int

            if (height > 4096 || width > 4096 || height < 256 || width < 256) {
                print("Size not valid")
            } else {
                print("Size is valid")
            }
        }
    }

} catch {
    print("File attributes cannot be read")
}
```

Comment: yes for the file size it's ok, but not for height and width, this probably needs to be combined with something else

Comment: can you add 
let imageFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
        if let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(imageFileUrl as CFURL, nil) {
           if let imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0, nil) as Dictionary? {
                let width = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth] as! Int
                let height = imageProperties[kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight] as! Int
                if (height > 4096 || width > 4096 || height < 256 || width < 256) { return false }
            }
        }

so I can mark your answer as answered ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to do is is to scan for the image's SOFx marker. The SOF market contains the image size.

On of many sources giving the marker structure:

http://lad.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/multimidia/jpegmarker.pdf